# html audio player in ios

Tags: html, ios, vue.js

My problem is in the sound player code on Apple phones and it gives an error message if it works correctly on PC and Android.
`<audio controls>   <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>`

I expected the file to be executed like all devices, but I have an error message on the Apple device and I did not find a solution

Comment: What error message are you getting? Would be good to include that in the question.